# Why does writing to this socket discard the read buffer (and is that really what's happening)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, sockets

Consider the following snippet:

```
QTcpServer server;
server.listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost);

QTcpSocket clientSocket;
clientSocket.connectToHost(server.serverAddress(), server.serverPort());

// ...wait for connection to succeed...

QTcpSocket *serverSocket = server.nextPendingConnection();
serverSocket->write("test");
serverSocket->close();
```

The goal of this snippet is to create two connected sockets by creating a `QTcpServer` that listens for incoming connections and connecting to it with another `QTcpSocket`. Once the connection is established, data is written to one of the sockets and it is closed.

`QAbstractSocket::close()` [invokes `disconnectFromHost()`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/5.5/src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp#L2635) The [documentation for `QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#disconnectFromHost) clearly states that:

> If there is pending data waiting to be written, QAbstractSocket will enter ClosingState and wait until all data has been written.

The next snippet enters the event loop briefly to process pending events and then attempts to read the string from the other socket:

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
qDebug() << clientSocket.readAll();
```

This prints `"test"` and all is well. Or perhaps not. If I modify the previous snippet by prepending a call to `write()`, the data can no longer be read from the socket:

```
clientSocket.write("test");
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
qDebug() << clientSocket.readAll();
```

This prints an empty string (`""`) instead of the expected value from the previous run. Why can't the socket read the value this time?

**Note:** this *only* manifests itself on the Windows platform. Neither Linux nor Mac OS X builds of Qt exhibit this behavior, instead printing the expected value in both cases.

**Second note:** if you want to play with the code, there's a working Gist here: https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/ee6116d120903db84384

**Third note:** here's a screenshot of a Wireshark capture of the TCP exchange:

[image]

Comment: My guess: since the other end of the socket is closed, I would expect the attempt to write to it to put the socket in an error state, and perhaps to cause it to automatically close.  Whether data can still be read from the socket afterwards may well be implementation-dependent.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the first write and the close operations don't take place until the `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` line (I verified this with the debugger). It may still be that they are processed out-of-order though.

Comment: If there is no guarantee about ordering, it might be working on UNIX only because Qt happens to choose to process the clientSocket.write() before it processes the serverSocket.close().  But it could also be due to differences in the underlying socket implementation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've added a screenshot of the TCP exchange in case that helps shed light on the order of events. The first `write()` is immediately acknowledged and then a `FIN` packet is sent and acknowledged before the client socket writes anything.

Comment: How does that compare to the sequence of events on Linux / MacOSX?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: here's what I see on Linux: http://i.stack.imgur.com/txaAq.png

Comment: One extra ACK in Windows.  Probably not significant.  I'm still guessing this is just down to the way the underlying implementations respond to the RST, and that the only robust solution is to not write data to a closed socket - or at least not until you've already read whatever incoming data you need.

Comment: Generally speaking, "here's a link to the code" is considered bad form on SO. The code should be minimized and posted as a part of the question. We're talking of <50 lines of code, come on.

Answer (score 0):

Im not very familiar with Qt, but on Windows, there is no Fork. You are trying to fit to parallel tasks on the same thread, but you should have the client running on a different thread than the server.

Comment: The OP isn't using fork() on the other platforms either.

Comment: I never worked on Linux, maybe the API is doing this?

Comment: Windows supports asynchronous I/O, and I would expect Qt to make use of that, so it isn't necessarily true that you need multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing asynchronous code in synchronous style in a way that doesn't ensure that you wait long enough for things to happen. Calling `processEvents` simply means "do any work that is currently available to do" not "do work and/or wait for work until no more work can possibly arrive". You treat it like the latter, but it means the former.

The simplest fix is not to do that.

Connect slots or functors to relevant socket signals, and return control to the event loop. Never use `waitForXxx` functions, they simply aren't specified sufficiently to allow use in all cases. Never mind the horrible reentrancy issues you'll face when reentering the event loop.

If there's no event loop in the thread where your code runs, spin up your own:

```
QEventLoop loop;

...
connect(serverSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected,
        &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec(); // this will keep executing until the socked is disconnected
```

Comment: Good point. I've got an example [here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/ee6116d120903db84384#file-testsocketbug-cpp-L29) though that uses `QTRY_COMPARE` instead of `processEvents()` and it still exhibits the same behavior. `QTRY_COMPARE()` creates an event loop and runs it until either the two values are equal or a timeout is reached.

Comment: @NathanOsman Try not closing the sending socket at all and see if the data is received. If so, then it's possible that on Windows there's an implementation bug somewhere, or a platform limitation. You really need to provide a complete, self-contained, single-file test case in your question, though.

Comment: But I did. The link is right at the bottom of the question.